# outer join causing TABLE ACCESS (FULL) which causes massive performance issues

Tags: oracle

I have a large query, part of this query contains several joins in the where clause and the joins are according to the execution plan causing TABLE ACCESS (FULL), which is causing the query to run very slow, obviously.

Here is the part of the query that seems to be causing the issue

```
WHERE ......    
   A.CN= B.CN(+) AND 
   A.CI= B.CI(+) AND    
   A.SO= B.SO(+) AND  
   A.CN= C.CN(+) AND
```

The execution plan shows

HASH JOIN (RIGHT OUTER)

Access Predicates: "A"."CN"="C"."CN"

Estimated bytes is 700MB which is 1/3 of this entire queries cost.

I have checked indexes and both tables have indexes on CN.

Im just beginning to learn about performance and how things work so im sorry if this is a dumb question :x

Looking for advice on how to improve performance.

Comment: Is this your entire WHERE condition? On which table you have the Full Table Scan? You should provide the entire query and full execution plan, otherwise you hardly get any help.

Comment: No it is a much much larger query in reality, but according to the execution plan its A.CN= B.CN(+) that is causing the biggest issue.

The full table scan is on table C

Comment: Again, with such little information you will not receive any help.

Comment: Please let me know which information might be helpful and ill provide it, I was hoping this information would be enough.

Comment: Did you read my comment? You should provide the **entire query** and **full execution plan**

Comment: A full table scan isn't necessarily the worst approach. Also, the cost isn't generally useful when looking at the execution plan, especially when it's the "wrong" plan.

Comment: Sorry I missed that bit. The entire query is about 1000 rows and id have to rename each and every identificator before posting.

So without this full query and exec plan there is really no way of telling why oracle performs a full scan here?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson What is the best to look at then? 
Can you please elaborate on "Wrong" plan?

Comment: Execution plan should be the first thing to look into. But execution plan could be wrong and misleading if table statistics are inaccurate (e.g. old or haven't been refreshed after massive DML statements). So besides presenting "entire query and full execution plan" it's worth to post some tables statistics...